# How to remove strangely named ref from remote git server?

Tags: git

I've manged to get a ref named '../../HEAD' in my remote git repo, which I'd like to delete because it prints a warning when cloning:

> error: * Ignoring funny ref 'refs/remotes/origin/../../HEAD' locally

But git proper doesn't like that as a refspec, so it won't let me `git push origin --delete '../../HEAD'.

I don't have direct access to the remote server, how can I delete this ref?

Comment: You probably can't—you probably need to get someone who does have direct access to log in and fix it there. How it got created there is a bit of a mystery....

Comment: Through a third-party tool that can't seem to delete it =D

Comment: Are you looking for `git update-ref -d HEAD`? But read the manpage first.